# What is the minimum value of the given expression?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I had seen an expression in three variables as follows:

> $$F(x,y,z)= \sum_{cyc} {|x+y|\over|x|+|y|}$$

I was asked by my teacher to find the range of values that $F$ can take. I could easily find that the maxima attained was $3$ but I was a bit shocked when he said that the lower bound of $F$ was $1$. Could someone please explain it to me why a value less than $1$ is not possible?

Comment: that's because you have three values/variables so two of them are bound to have the same sign, in which case one of the sums will be $1$

Comment: Oh yeah, I got it. Thank you.